ScyllaDB hierarchical data storage
I have a data in below format
- Country (Root Object)
  - State 
    - City

Each Country, State and City has an Id assigned to it.

Country has CountryID
State has StatueID
City has CityID

API which is connected to the ScyllaDB has the below Usecases

If user requests CityID, he has to get StateID and CountryID (All parent Ids)
If user requests CountryID, he has to get all StateIDs and CityIDs (All child Ids)

Question

What is the best way to store hierarchical data like above in ScyllaDB.
Want to save data in 1 table without duplicate data.


"Want to save data in 1 table without duplicate data." - then you should not use Scylla in general, since the design  paradigm behind it - table per query and a lot of data duplication =)
